# Making a list of suggestions from a table in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mention

I want to develop a some king of an autocomplete system that when the user is using @ and then start typing a name of a place ( Places are stored in DataBase) it bring a list of suggestions that start with the same letters so the user can choose from one of them.

Considering that I'm using Nodejs and MongoDB as the data base.

My basic Idea was to get the places name in serverside and share it with the client-side js code. But I have no idea how to develop the javascript part.

Comment: why don't u use google maps places API ?

Comment: If you store a set of suggestions specific to your application, then have a look at the XMLHttpRequest object of JavaScript. Otherwise I would not recommend reinventing the wheel.